# Index out of range when adding row to gridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an index out of range exception while trying to add an empty row to a gridview. This is the code behind. There are more columns, I just removed them to shorten the code.

```
   Private Sub AddNewGridRow()
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dtCurrentData As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentData"), DataTable)
            Dim drCurrentRow As DataRow = Nothing
            If dtCurrentData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentData.Rows.Count
                    Dim lblVoucher As Label = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("lblVoucher"), Label)

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentData.NewRow()
                    drCurrentRow("RecID") = i + 1

                    dtCurrentData.Rows(i - 1)("RecID") = lblVoucher
                    rowIndex += 1
                Next
                dtCurrentData.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow)
                ViewState("CurrentData") = dtCurrentData
                GridView1.DataBind()
            End If
        Else
            Response.Write("ViewState is null")
        End If
        SetPreviousData()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetPreviousData()
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentData"), DataTable)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    'Out of range exception happens here when trying to fill the previous data.
                    Dim lblVoucher As Label = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).FindControl("lblVoucher"), Label)

                    lblVoucher.Text = dt.Rows(i)("Voucher").ToString()

                    rowIndex += 1
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

And this is the aspx for that column.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Voucher" SortExpression="RecID">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblVoucher" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RecID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Try changing `For i As Integer = 1 To dtCurrentData.Rows.Count` to  `For i As Integer = 0 To dtCurrentData.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: Still getting index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code into debug and see which portion of the statement is causing the exception.

You have two possible problems:

1. You do not have enough rows to meet the rowIndex requirement.
2. You do not have enough cells to meet the cells(1) requirement.

I would try rewriting the problem line as follows:

```
    Dim lblVoucher As Label = Nothing

    If GridView1.Rows.Count < rowIndex Then
        Dim oRow As DataGridViewRow

        oRow = GridView1.Rows(rowIndex)
        If oRow.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            lblVoucher = TryCast(oRow.Cells(1).FindControl("lblVoucher"), Label)
        Else
            ' Do something here when you don't have cells
        End If
    Else
        ' Do something here when you don't have a row
    End If
```

You can set breakpoints or throw exceptions or whatever is appropriate for your application in the else clauses when you don't have what you are expecting.